# find a specifik obejct with arrays and print it out, react

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks

I want to use find when clicking a button, I want to find an obejct  (working in react)

```
  let numbers = [
    { id: 0, namn: one, img: "../number/one" },
    { id: 1, namn: two, img: "../number/two" },
    { id: 2, namn: three, img: "../number/three" },
  ];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
    id: 0,
    name: "one",
    img: "../number/one",
  });

  const count = useRef(0);

  function next() {
    if (count.current === 2) {
      count.current = 0;
      let found = numbers.find((number) => number.id === count.current);
    } else {
      count.current = count.current + 1;
      let foundtwo = numbers.find((number) => number.id === count.current);
    }

    return (
      <>
        <img>{selected.img}</img>
        namn: {selected.name}
      </>
    );
  }
```

I can find it but I want to put it in a useState.
or somehow get it to show. how can I get found, and found two out in the return

Answer (score 0):

the awswer was to put a

```
if( found === undefined){
console.log("error")
}else{
setSelected(found)
}
```